# Rake aborted with zero failed test cases

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, rake, watir

For my product I use rake for the test-case-execution based on Watir and Selenium. The execution is handled by Jenkins.
In the last two runs my test-suite has ran successful (0 errors/failures) anyway in the end of the log I can see, that rake throws and error anyway which leads to a negative run on jenkins because rake has not ended with RC0. Even if the rake message is "Rake aborted" the test-results are written and found by jenkins successfully.

Output:

```
96 tests, 3992 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Writing XML reports to /home/test/admin/jenkins/system/workspace/projectname/Tests/results
rake aborted!
```

Version

```
> gem list rake
rake (12.0.0)
```

Updating rake to a new version is not possible at the moment because it is a company-wide used machine and for some reason this problem only occures for us.

Nothing more is printed out by rake.
Any ideas what could cause the problem or where to find more informations?

Comment: *"Nothing more is printed out by rake"* -- Well, that's weird. Some error has happened, and no error message is visible? Are you suppressing output somehow, e.g. piping it to a file? What happens if you run the command manually, rather than through CI?

Comment: *"Updating rake to a new version is not possible"* -- I can't necessarily say that updating `rake` will resolve anything (chances are, it won't!), but "it's a company-wide machine" is not a valid excuse. `rake` is a ruby gem. Your project has a `Gemfile.lock`, which specifies a version of `rake` to use. In other words, it is totally possible/valid to have different versions of `rake` per-project, even on a so-called "company-wide used machine".

Comment: My best guess, given the very limited information/clues above, is that something in the "Writing XML reports" step is failing silently, e.g. due to the `/Tests/results` folder not existing. (Also, by the way, why is the `Tests` folder name written with a capital `T`??!)